# Why wkhtmltopdf converts Chinese characters into English characters？

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, chinese-locale

I encountered a strange question when I use wkhtmltopdf, some of the Chinese characters in my html page are converted to English characters.

**this is my html page.**
[image]

**and this is wkhtmltopdf generate pdf file**
[image]

Does anyone encounter a similar problem?

**This is my html code block，this html page generate from apidoc library.**

```js
<script id="template-article-compare-param-block" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#if source}}
    {{#each_compare_keys source.fields compare.fields}}
      {{#if typeSame}}
        <h2>{{__ source.key}}</h2>
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 30%">{{#if ../_col1}}{{__ ../_col1}}{{else}}{{__ "Field"}}{{/if}}</th>
            {{#if ../_hasType}}<th style="width: 10%">{{__ "Type"}}</th>{{/if}}
            <th style="width: {{#if ../_hasType}}60%{{else}}70%{{/if}}">{{__ "Description"}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {{subTemplate "article-compare-param-block-body" source=source.value compare=compare.value _hasType=../_hasType}}
        </table>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if typeIns}}
        <h2><ins>{{__ source.key}}</ins></h2>
        <table class="ins">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 30%">{{#if ../_col1}}{{__ ../_col1}}{{else}}{{__ "Field"}}{{/if}}</th>
            {{#if ../_hasType}}<th style="width: 10%">{{__ "Type"}}</th>{{/if}}
            <th style="width: {{#if ../_hasType}}60%{{else}}70%{{/if}}">{{__ "Description"}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {{subTemplate "article-compare-param-block-body" source=source.value compare=source.value _hasType=../_hasType}}
        </table>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if typeDel}}
        <h2><del>{{__ compare.key}}</del></h2>
        <table class="del">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 30%">{{#if ../_col1}}{{__ ../_col1}}{{else}}{{__ "Field"}}{{/if}}</th>
            {{#if ../_hasType}}<th style="width: 10%">{{__ "Type"}}</th>{{/if}}
            <th style="width: {{#if ../_hasType}}60%{{else}}70%{{/if}}">{{__ "Description"}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {{subTemplate "article-compare-param-block-body" source=compare.value compare=compare.value _hasType=../_hasType}}
        </table>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each_compare_keys}}

    {{#if source.examples}}
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-examples">
    {{#each_compare_title source.examples compare.examples}}
      {{#if typeSame}}
        <li{{#if_eq index compare=0}} class="active"{{/if_eq}}>
          <a href="#{{../../section}}-compare-examples-{{../../article.id}}-{{index}}">{{{showDiff source.title compare.title}}}</a>
        </li>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if typeIns}}
        <li{{#if_eq index compare=0}} class="active"{{/if_eq}}>
          <a href="#{{../../section}}-compare-examples-{{../../article.id}}-{{index}}"><ins>{{{source.title}}}</ins></a>
        </li>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if typeDel}}
        <li{{#if_eq index compare=0}} class="active"{{/if_eq}}>
          <a href="#{{../../section}}-compare-examples-{{../../article.id}}-{{index}}"><del>{{{compare.title}}}</del></a>
        </li>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each_compare_title}}
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
    {{#each_compare_title source.examples compare.examples}}

      {{#if typeSame}}
        <div class="tab-pane{{#if_eq index compare=0}} active{{/if_eq}}" id="{{../../section}}-compare-examples-{{../../article.id}}-{{index}}">
          <pre class="prettyprint language-{{source.type}}" data-type="{{source.type}}"><code>{{{showDiff source.content compare.content}}}</code></pre>
        </div>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if typeIns}}
        <div class="tab-pane{{#if_eq index compare=0}} active{{/if_eq}}" id="{{../../section}}-compare-examples-{{../../article.id}}-{{index}}">
          <pre class="prettyprint language-{{source.type}}" data-type="{{source.type}}"><code>{{{source.content}}}</code></pre>
        </div>
      {{/if}}

      {{#if typeDel}}
        <div class="tab-pane{{#if_eq index compare=0}} active{{/if_eq}}" id="{{../../section}}-compare-examples-{{../../article.id}}-{{index}}">
          <pre class="prettyprint language-{{source.type}}" data-type="{{compare.type}}"><code>{{{compare.content}}}</code></pre>
        </div>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each_compare_title}}
    </div>
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML.

Comment: I have updated my question,added my HTML code block, my HTML is generate from apidoc library.@PatrickMlr